# cmi.exit scorm 2004 4th edition

Tags: scorm2004

Does "cmi.exit" value shall be saved between learner attempts? Or just we keep it value in a specific attempt?

- I am building a scorm 2004 LMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `cmi.exit` is not saved from one learner attempt to the next.  It shall be set to `""` at the beginning of each learner attempt.

Actually, the value of `cmi.exit` is set to `""` at the beginning of each learner *session*, and one or more learner sessions form a learner attempt.

Source:  [SCORM 2004 4th edition Runtime Environment Book](http://www.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/2004%204th%20Edition/Documentation.aspx), available from adlnet.gov (download the documentation suite).

Comment: Thanks a lot E-man , and what about cmi.entry ?shall it be saved between learner attempts ?

Comment: From the SCO's standpoint, cmi.exit is never saved, and is always set to "" at the start of a learner session (and attempt).